# Does my computer have 1 or 2 CPUs? (cpuinfo and lscpu differ)

Tags: cpu, cpuinfo

When I run `cat /proc/cpuinfo` I get the following output (only the relevant line included):

```
cpu cores: 1
```

However, `lscpu` gives me the following output:

```
CPU(s): 2
```

Which of the two is correct, and more importantly, why are they giving me different results?

---

The full output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` is:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 15
model       : 3
model name  : Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 2.80GHz
stepping    : 4
microcode   : 0xe
cpu MHz     : 2800.135
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 5
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe constant_tsc pebs bts pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl cid xtpr
bogomips    : 5600.27
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 128
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 15
model       : 3
model name  : Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 2.80GHz
stepping    : 4
microcode   : 0xe
cpu MHz     : 2800.135
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 5
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe constant_tsc pebs bts pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl cid xtpr
bogomips    : 5600.27
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 128
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
power management:
```

The full output of `lscpu` is:

```
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            15
Model:                 3
Stepping:              4
CPU MHz:               2800.135
BogoMIPS:              5600.27
L1d cache:             16K
L2 cache:              1024K
```

(This can also be viewed at https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/f3f9139b8968987d3716.)

Comment: those commands tell us your CPU and the information can then be determined. Please update your question with the output of your commands or at least `lscpu | grep Model`

Comment: @bodhi.zazen The full output for both commands has been added to the question.

Comment: I have a guess at what happened; `cpuinfo` has two "sections", one for each core. I missed this when looking at the output in a smaller terminal window, however, it became very visible to me when the full output was pasted into a Gist. Can someone confirm that this is indeed how `cpuinfo` displays its output?

Comment: Please re-read the output. Both show two single-core cpus, I do not see a contradiction.

Comment: The `cpuinfo` output shows information per execution threads.  An Intel CPU with HyperThreading will show one output block per "thread".  The `cpuinfo` output will contain one block per core on a multi-core CPU, or simply one block per populated socket.  The output of `cpuinfo` gets really long when you have multiple Intel CPUs, each with multiple cores and HyperThreading enabled.

Comment: `/proc/cpuinfo` show the total number of **logical** cpus. A logical cpu can be a hyperthreading sibling, a shared core in a dual or quad core, or a separate physical cpu.

So, the result is: 
1 physical cpu 1 core with hyperthreading enabled. 

see https://linuxhunt.blogspot.com/2010/03/understanding-proccpuinfo.html

Answer (score 14):

This is consistent with having a single processor containing a single core which contains two execution threads through [hyperthreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading). Thus you have two logical processors, but they share most of their resources (instruction decoding, arithmetic, etc.). This allows some parallelism — one thread can progress while the other one is blocked (e.g. waiting for a memory access) while keeping the hardware cost down (fewer components than two independent cores).

Look at the rest of the output from `lscpu` and the content of `/proc/cpuinfo`. See [So what are logical cpu cores (as opposed to physical cpu cores)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88283/so-what-are-logical-cpu-cores-as-opposed-to-physical-cpu-cores) for an example.

Comment: Really it's only the out-of-order execution core that is shared in a processor with hyperthreading.  Each virtual CPU has instruction decoding.